# How to hide server version for custom errors in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image: Error page displaying iis server version]Hi I am developing web application in .net mvc. I am hiding server version using     `<remove name="X-Powered-By" />` in customheaders. It works fine and i am able to hide iis version. This works for pages that exists only. Also i have implemented

```
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="Errorpage.html" mode="On">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Login/Index" />
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Login/Index" />
    </customErrors>
```

for custom errors. for example, if i try to access page that does not exists then i will be redirected to Errorpage.html but in this case server version is visible to users.

Below is my global.asax code.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;

        }
        protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
        {
            Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            Response.Headers.Set("Server", "");
            Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version"); //alternative to above solution
            Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version"); //alternative to above solution
        }
```

[image: new custom error]
May i know how can i fix this issue in either cases pages that exists and pages that does not exists! may i get some help to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom error page for 404 and add this to your web.config file.

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/PageNotFound" />
```

Where PageNotFound is your  action in HomeController which returns view.

Now open your Global.asax.cs file to Application_Start, and add this code at the top:

```
MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
```

you can eliminate the "Server" header by adding a handler to PreSendRequestHeaders event like this:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    if (app != null &&
        app.Context != null)
    {
        app.Context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks? What about server version?

Comment: you can create your own html in the view which simply says Page not Found!.There will be no server version visible to users.

Comment: As you told i have created my own html page and still displaying iis server version. Please find the screen shot i have added just now.

Comment: Hey Praveen i already have that in my global.asax. I just added above. I hope you have not understood what i am looking for. Pages that exists i am able to hide server version. Pages that doesnt exist i am not able to hide server version. I tried to explain clearly as much as i can.

Comment: You need to create an action that returns view  and in that view you can add  your custom html . Currently your url for the page is like : localhost:62777/errorpage.html /aspxerrorpath=/Dashboard1         but it should be like  localhost:62777/home/pagenotfound

Comment: I have created seperate action method with view errorview. If i try to access the page that does not exists i get screen(i have attached above just now). but in my errorview file i have good custom error i cant display that. is there any way i can get that?

Comment: Can you please share the details of youe web.config file after following the above cases